# How to plot curve, not dots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot dependency, but it shows dots plot. I try to plot dependency of error from w1 parameter and recieve dots plot.

I tried some documentation examples, but it always shows empty plot. Two things work only, when i use 'ro' and 'k^'

Here is plot code.
How can I do it with curve, instead of dots?

```
for w1 in range(-10,10):
    err_ = (data['Height'][3] - (50 + w1*data['Weight'][3]))**2
    err = []
    err.append(err_)
    w = []
    w.append(w1)
    plt.plot(w, err, 'k^')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your code a bit. Following are the changes:

- Initialize the empty lists just once *before* the for loop (You were reinitializing the empty lists during each iteration of the for loop so the previous appended values were overwritten)
- Move the plot command *after* the for loop so that all values are plotted at once.

---

```
err = []
w = []

for w1 in range(-10,10):
    err_ = (data['Height'][3] - (50 + w1*data['Weight'][3]))**2
    err.append(err_)
    w.append(w1)

plt.plot(w, err, 'k^')
```